# Starting server in Weblogic: "I/O error while writing to file The process cannot access the file because it is beign used by another proccess

Tags: weblogic, nodemanager, weblogic14c

I need help with solving issue with Weblogic. In freshly installed WebLogic 14.1.1 I've created new server and machine for this server. I have working NodeManager launched in CMD, but when I try to start the server (new or one I've configured earlier) I get error from NodeManager that result in FAILED_NON_RESTARTABLE state. What I get from the NodeManager logs, it tries to access this server log file, but it fails with error from title. I've tried to reinstall everything but nothing seems to work.

```
<13:17:20> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Startup configuration properties loaded from "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\data\nodemanager\startup.properties">
<13:17:20> <INFO> <Server Implementation Class: weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer$ClassicServer.>
<13:17:20> <INFO> <Secure socket listener started on port 5556, host localhost/127.0.0.1>
<15:06:18> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Boot identity properties saved to "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\data\nodemanager\boot.properties">
<15:06:18> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Startup configuration properties saved to "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\data\nodemanager\startup.properties">
<15:06:18> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Rotated server output log to "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\logs\Server-0.out00006">
<15:06:18> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server error log also redirected to server log>
<15:06:18> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Starting WebLogic server with command line: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd >
<15:06:18> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Working directory is 'C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain'>
<15:06:18> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server output log file is 'C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\logs\Server-0.out'>
<15:06:23> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <The server 'Server-0' with process id 4796 is no longer alive; waiting for the process to die.>
<15:06:23> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Rotated server output log to "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\logs\Server-0.out00007">
<15:06:23> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server error log also redirected to server log>
<15:06:23> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server failed during startup. It may be retried according to the auto restart configuration.>
<15:06:23> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server failed so attempting to restart (restart count = 1)>
<15:06:23> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Rotated server output log to "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\logs\Server-0.out00008">
<15:06:23> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server error log also redirected to server log>
<15:06:23> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Starting WebLogic server with command line: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd >
<15:06:23> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Working directory is 'C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain'>
<15:06:23> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server output log file is 'C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\logs\Server-0.out'>
<15:06:28> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <The server 'Server-0' with process id 20156 is no longer alive; waiting for the process to die.>
<15:06:28> <WARNING> <base_domain> <Server-0> <I/O error while writing to file "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\logs\Server-0.out">
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\logs\Server-0.out (Proces nie mo┐e uzyskaŠ dostŕpu do pliku, poniewa┐ jest on u┐ywany przez inny proces)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:293)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
        at java.base/java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:113)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.InternalInstanceCustomizer.log(InternalInstanceCustomizer.java:77)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.WLSInstanceCustomizer.log(WLSInstanceCustomizer.java:23)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.ServerMonitor.log(ServerMonitor.java:773)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.ServerMonitor.log(ServerMonitor.java:777)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.ServerMonitor.info(ServerMonitor.java:782)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.ServerMonitor.runMonitor(ServerMonitor.java:531)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.ServerMonitor.run(ServerMonitor.java:487)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

<15:06:28> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Rotated server output log to "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\logs\Server-0.out00009">
<15:06:28> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server error log also redirected to server log>
<15:06:28> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server failed during startup. It may be retried according to the auto restart configuration.>
<15:06:28> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server failed so attempting to restart (restart count = 2)>
<15:06:28> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Rotated server output log to "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\logs\Server-0.out00010">
<15:06:28> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server error log also redirected to server log>
<15:06:28> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Starting WebLogic server with command line: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd >
<15:06:28> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Working directory is 'C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain'>
<15:06:28> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server output log file is 'C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\logs\Server-0.out'>
<15:06:32> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <The server 'Server-0' with process id 4648 is no longer alive; waiting for the process to die.>
<15:06:32> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Rotated server output log to "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\Server-0\logs\Server-0.out00011">
<15:06:32> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server error log also redirected to server log>
<15:06:32> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server failed during startup. It may be retried according to the auto restart configuration.>
<15:06:32> <INFO> <base_domain> <Server-0> <Server failed but will not be restarted because the maximum number of restart attempts has been exceeded>
<15:06:32> <WARNING> <Server start command for WebLogic server 'Server-0' failed due to: [Server failed to start up but Node Manager was not aware of the reason]. Please check Node Manager log and/or server 'Server-0' log for detailed information.>
```

(*Note: date information removed from log file for readability.*)

I've installed Weblogic12c and same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've accidently found anwser after messing around. Node manager logs are missleading. I thought that problem was with my computer configuration, tried different java versions, different weblogic versions etc. In my case it was port conflict. **Port that I configured was already in use**.

In weblogic 12, then I later got same error in NM, but now server logs were helpful.